# QtCreator cant find local shared library .so

Tags: qt, build, shared-libraries

In the QtCreator .pro project file of an app i am specifying a shared library (libasdf.so on linux) which i want to use. However QtCreator cant find the library.

Directory structure (i am not allowed to change this) is as follows:

```
project/apps/app --> this is $$PWD
    app.pro
project/build
    libasdf.so.1.0.0 --> the actual binary
    libasdf.so.1.0   ⎫
    libasdf.so.1     ⎬--> symbolic links to the binary
    libasdf.so       ⎭
project/asdf/src
    project/asdf/src/include
project/work --> this is where the app is built and run
```

In the app.pro file I have:

```
DESTDIR = $$PWD/../../work

# library headers
# $$PWD is directory containing this .pro file
INCLUDEPATH += $$PWD/../../asdf/src/
DEPENDPATH += $$PWD/../../asdf/src/

# library binaries
unix: LIBS += -L$$PWD/../../build -lasdf
```

For some reason when i build, i get this error:

```
Starting /usr/bin/primusrun...
./app: error while loading shared libraries: libmarion.so.1:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have to run the app using a custom Run configuration using `/usr/bin/primusrun ./app` (see bumblebee project, a kind of alternative to NVidia Optimus) to use my dedicated graphics device.
Note that it works when the `libasdf.so` is installed in `/usr/lib`.

In the project "Run" configuration in QtCreator, the working directory is set to `project/work`.

But why is the library path not added?

Answer (score 2):

By default the paths you add to your `LIBS` will be added to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the run environment variables.

However sometimes these changes do not take place right away.

To solve this issue:

- Close qtcreator
- Delete the `.pro.user` file
- Open qtcreator again and open your project

Or you could always manually add your paths to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` if you don't want to restart qtcreator right now.

Answer (score 1):

As i was writing this question, i stumbled over this checkbox in the default Run configuration (without `/usr/bin/primusrun`) which said

> ☑ Add build library search path to LD_LIBRARY_PATH

With this ticked, it runs fine.
However i realized that in the custom Run configuration window, there is no such checkbox, and the library path set via `LIBS +=` was never added to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`!

By adding it manually to the environment variables, it runs fine!

However i am wondering, is there no way to automize this, such that the definition in the .pro file is sufficient?